# I have my axios calls data printed in the terminal

Tags: firebase, vue.js, visual-studio-code, axios, nuxt.js

I don't know how to explain it better: I'm using Visual Studio Code, Nuxt and Axios, and whenever I refresh my app in the browser I get all the content of my axios call printed in the vsc terminal.

I think I may have made some changes in the google inspector but I'm not sure.

[image: first picture of vsc terminal]

[image: second picture of vsc terminal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing strange here, Nuxt is running on both client side and server side. Here, you have a `console.log` probably called in a context when both are available.

On top of that, the initial request is always coming from the server hence why you can see it in your terminal.

Similar to a Node.js app, the output of your `console.log` is on the "backend" aka you terminal here.

Comment: @Elisaniza yeah, either running it only on the client side side or removing it will fix this "issue". Give a read to the lifecycle: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#nuxt-lifecycle